# How to render the material/colour of a 3d mesh without the use of a .mtl file but just with a .obj file in android. Is there any way to read obj?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, 3d, opengl-es

The problem is that mesh through obj renders without colour/material or texture but displays a coloured mesh when opened through meshlab. The question is whether it is possible to display coloured mesh without the use of .mtl just by the obj?